# How to load an image in a div from jQuery dynamically without delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am attempting to load an image in jQuery, on hover, to another div without a delay for load times.

**[HERE IS A WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V3YeK/)**

**Raw code:**

*HTML:*

```
<div id="hover" data-img="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-370-289-5.jpg">
    HOVER OVER ME
</div>

<div id="image">
    <span>
        <img data-img="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-370-289-4.jpg" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-370-289-4.jpg" />
    </span>
</div>
```

*jQuery:*

```
$('#hover').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var newImg = $(this).attr('data-img');
    $('#image > span > img').attr("src", newImg);
});
$('#hover').on('mouseleave', function() {
    var oldImg = $('#image > span > img').attr('data-img');
    $('#image > span > img').attr("src", oldImg);
});
```

As you can see, the image of the animal takes a little while to load. I need to remove this delay completely so that the image of the animal is displayed right away upon hover.

**Things I have tried:**

- I tried reducing my images file size from 120kb down to just 20kb,
  still no luck.
- I tried loading my images to a hidden div upon page load so that
  they already existed within the page, instead of just within a
  `data` attribute, still no luck.

---

*PS. The version on my site contains more than 30 images, while the example is only using two. The example has very small images that could possibly be loaded straight away with fast internet. We have horrible internet speeds in our office, so if the images load straight away, try sourcing some larger images to see the problem at hand.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a simple preloading technique like

```
$('#hover').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var newImg = $(this).attr('data-img');
    $('#image > span > img').attr("src", newImg);
});
$('#hover').on('mouseleave', function() {
    var oldImg = $('#image > span > img').attr('data-img');
    $('#image > span > img').attr("src", oldImg);
});

//preload here
new Image().src = $('#hover').data('img');
```

Comment: Just producing some tests on your code now. Will let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Worked like a cham. Was definitely very easy to implement since I could put it into a loop and load all my images easily instead of changing a heap of DOM elements around. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is put an actual `<img src="url">` and hide it through css.

This way, the image will have been loaded already and there will be no delay when you hover over the image.

Try this:

```
<div id="hover" data-img="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-370-289-5.jpg">
    HOVER OVER ME
</div>

<div id="image">
    <span>
        <img data-img="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-370-289-4.jpg" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-370-289-4.jpg" />
    </span>
</div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-370-289-5.jpg" style="display:none">
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/V3YeK/1/)

Comment: Great work around. But unfortunately, it would involve me changing a heap of DOM elements around. The preloading technique that  Arun suggested was more suitable for me. Thank you for your input though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want delay, then you have to load the image BEFORE you show it via hover. Arun's answer will work.

Another option is to use an image sprite. Put both images together as one image file. Then reposition it so that the appropriate part of it is shown via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the "src" attribute the browser parses and tries to load the specified image.

I suggest you to hide/show div element already containing the image like this.

```
<div id="hover" data-img="img-id-1">
    HOVER OVER ME
</div>
<div id="img-id-1" style="display:none"><img src="/path/to/img.png"/></div>

<div id="image"></div>

$(document).on('mouseenter', '#hover', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-img');
    $('#image').html($(id).html());
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '#hover', function() {
  $('#image').empty();
});
```

I have not added the default image to display it first. It should be easy to add however.